# Line in a plane perpendicular to line

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, plane-geometry

I want to find a line in the plane denoted by points $P_0=(0,0,0)$,$P_1=(2,2,0)$,$P_2=(0,1,-2)$. The line I am looking for have to be perpendicular to line
$${x+1\over3}={y-1\over2}={z\over{1\over2}}$$

What I have done so far:

$\vec n=\vec{P_0P_1} \times \vec{P_0P_2}=-4i-4j+2k$ is perpendicular to the plane

Then $\vec a=<3,2,{1\over2}>$ is in the direction of the given line.

The line I am searching for is of the form $\vec r=\vec x+t\vec b$. So I imagine I have to find $\vec x$ , $\vec b$

For $\vec b$ I know that $\vec b \perp \vec a$ whcih means $\vec b \cdot \vec a=0$
I also know that $\vec b \perp \vec n$ which means $\vec b \cdot \vec n=0$

Then If $\vec b=<b_1,b_2,b_3>$ I have two equations with 3 unknowns and I am missing one to be able to find $\vec b$.

I also don't know how to find $\vec x$

Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the normal to the plane is actually $$\left(\begin{matrix}-4\\4\\2\end{matrix}\right)$$ 
Then you want the direction of the required line to be perpendicular to this normal (i.e. parallel to the plane) and perpendicular to the line given with direction vector $$\left(\begin{matrix}3\\2\\\frac 12\end{matrix}\right)$$

Therefore work out the cross-product of these vectors to get the direction. However you need to be specific about what point you would like this line to pass through, since there are infinitely many possible choices.

Comment: Since the point the line pass through is not mentioned can I choose it arbitrary? E.g could it be the point where the 2 lines intersect?

Comment: The question as you have written it does not make this clear. Is that the complete wording of the question?

Comment: Yeap  I quoted the whole question. There is no reference as to from which point the line passes through.

Comment: OK so we assume the point of intersection of the plane and the given line is the point we must choose. The reason for this is that the phrase "line...perpendicular to the line" is often taken to mean that two lines must intersect in order to be perpendicular (although I disagree)

Comment: The line I am searching for is contained in the plane. The given line is perpendicular to the line I am searching for and the plane. So the intersection of the line with the plane has infinitely many solutions. And the only point I can find is the point resulting from the 2 lines intersection!

Comment: Can you find the Cartesian equation of the plane and solve this simultaneously with the given line to find the point of intersection? This is the point you need to make up the equation of the new line.

Comment: Yes I can do that, my point is why find the point of intersection of the given line and the plane and why not find the point of intersection of the 2 lines?

Comment: the new line must be perpendicular to the given line and contained in the plane, so passes through their point of intersection